# How do I implement a search bar in a Rails application that will use an API such as Yelp's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a Rails application that is using Postgres as the database. I want to be able to implement a search bar in one of my views that will get information from multiple APIs (perhaps Yelp and Eventbrite, maybe more). It would then display the results to the user.

I have not decided on how to filter these results. The user should then be able to save their favorite results, be able to look into these results' details, and share them with friends.

Which gems should I use? What is the best way to implement this search? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to how to implement an entire feature since that is outside the scope of this question. However I can give some advice. [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) is a great gem in my experience for reaching out to APIs. I would have a search_controller that the user posts to, and then have that controller use different plain ruby classes to reach out to the various APIs user HTTParty as the http client.

Answer (score 1):

For using API's like Yelp, Evenbrite or external API's you usually have to register to get full access to them. In any case, you may or may not have to login to the API.

Guessing that your search bar doesn't have autocomplete and you don't have to log in, you must create a controller that handles the search. That controller can call multiple models or wrappers, that each of one handles the API call to an specific provider.

If the provider doesn't have a gem, you can use this:
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/its-time-to-httparty

Other providers like Stripe i.e, do provide a gem. For those cases, i recommend to search in https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/, where you can find gems (type eventbrite in the search bar of this site). Those gems are rated by use, popularity and more. It's a good source of knowledge.

If you need to login to API's, you probably need to register your app so you can use it via a protocol, i.e Oauth, like the Github API.

Comment: Users have to log in to use the search functionality. Do you think it would be better to use their API or web scrape?

Comment: I would go to use their official API. We scraping sometimes its forbidden and dangerous, you can end up stealing info without consent.

Answer (score 1):

If the APIs you are reaching out to follow a restful format I have found this gem really helpful for treating restful APIs like active record associations: https://rubygems.org/gems/activeresource/versions/4.0.0